# Cordova/Phonegap File Transfer plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, file-upload, cordova-plugins

I'm using Cordova/Phonegap and I want to use a plugin for download a file and put it in Downloads folder. I find the plugin FileTransfer
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

I'm using this plugin but I don't known the path of folder Download in every device another i want to use the native notification of device...I read that I download the file from remote server but I don't where is and don't show the native console...this is my code in my controller

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var uri = encodeURI("http://someUrl/tost.pdf");
        var fileURL = "/sdcard/Download/tost.pdf";

        fileTransfer.download (uri, fileURL, function(entry) {
                console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
            },
            false,
            {
                headers: {
                    //"Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
                }
            }
        );
```

Do you know how I can use it with the native notification and the correct path where I must download it?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [apache/cordova-plugin-file github](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) you can see the locations where you can read from and write to listed in tables for iOS, Android and Blackberry 10.

From the looks of it you are trying to download to a sdcard on Android? The correct url would look like this:

```
var fileURL = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+"Download/tost.pdf";
```

I'm guessing you want to develop you app for iOS and Android, so you should use this url:

```
var fileURL = cordova.file.dataDirectory+"Download/tost.pdf";
```

since it's a valid url on both and it's persistent and private.

Comment: For use the cordova.file.dataDirectory must I import an plugin?

Comment: @user3751473 You just need the Cordova File plugin which should be added automaticly when you add the File Transfer plugin to your project.

Comment: When I added File Transfer, the plugin added this: org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.3 "File"
org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.5.0 "File Transfer"

Comment: Go to the project folder and type `cordova plugin ls` in the CLI, does it list cordova-plugin-file? If not just do `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file` and it should work

Comment: There isn't...I check it....now if I digit cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file I receive 404 not found

Comment: I receive an error...I think that it find this plugin but in the list i view org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.3 "File" and org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.5.0 "File Transfer"...but i must import it in my controller?

Comment: since it lists `org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.3 "File"` and `org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.5.0 "File Transfer"` the code should work

Comment: ok this is my respose Plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on android....doesn't work for me another how can I show notification? Do you known?

Comment: No, sorry but maybe you could use a local notification plugin for that. A quick google search for a cordova local notification plugin should give you a link to a github