# Save files from remote server into mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am working on Cordova 2015 Apache cordova app . I want to recieve files from remote server such as https://www.w3.org/2011/web-apps-ws/papers/Nitobi.pdf and save it into my device.

```
 $("#SaveFile").click(function () {
                        var _fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();


                var filePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "Download/tost.pdf";
                    var uri = encodeURI("https://www.w3.org/2011/web-apps-ws/papers/Nitobi.pdf");
                      _fileTransfer .download(
                 uri,
                 filePath,
                 function (entry) {
                     alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                 },
                 function (error) {
                     alert("download error source " + error.source);
                     alert("download error target " + error.target);
                     alert("upload error code" + error.code);
                 },
                 false,
                 {
                     headers: {
                         "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
                     }
                 }
             );
            });
```

When I 'v debugged it always go to error function 
1st error describe the source:
[image]

2nd error describe the target:
[image]

[image]

. and i didn't get any thing in download folder .

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages from your error handling code? If so, what are those messages?

Comment: No ,i have no error but i want to save this pdf file into my device , what should i write in filepath ?

Comment: In case you haven't seen it yet - take a look at the documentation for the Cordova file plugin. It has a section related to file paths that may help: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files

Comment: i have an error in var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer(); with message filetransfere is not a function

Comment: Sorry, I sent you a link to the wrong plugin. You'll want to first start by adding this plugin to your project: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer. Then you can get file paths from the file plugin. See if this post helps. If so, I'll summarize all this later as a formal answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021690/cordova-phonegap-file-transfer-plugin

Comment: I'v edit my post please check that . thanks

Comment: Are you getting error while downloading the file or saving the file ?  I see that you are having authorization code ? Do you require to authenticate ? If yes, how are you doing it ?

Comment: @Jagannath It goes to error function in downloading . My authorization code is optional as it declared here https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Comment: Hi, Is your issue resolved ?

Comment: No it is not solved yet

Answer (score 0):

here is a list of mobile paths from the w3c standard: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35605874/Planning%3A%20File%20API

and here is how you use it with phonegap: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem

so you have to request the file system onSuccess you can use the path

here a full example: [Writing and reading file in phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967696/writing-and-reading-file-in-phonegap)

Comment: Try the following code `fileSystem.root.getfile('download/myfile.jpg' ...)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574051/how-do-you-download-a-file-to-androids-downloads-using-phonegap

Comment: I am using visual studio cordova . I 'v  added file and file transfer plugins . Now LocalFileSystem didn't define in my code .